# JavaFX Stage - How to listen for deiconified events when maximized stage is minimized/restored?

Tags: javafx, stage

Add this to the primaryStage of any JavaFX application:

```
primaryStage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("iconified: " + primaryStage.isIconified());
});
```

- Minimize the stage. Output is "iconified: true".
- Restore the stage. Output is "iconified: false".
- Maximize the stage, then minimize it. Output is "iconified: true".
- Now restore the stage again. Output should be "iconified: false", but instead it prints nothing.

So my iconifiedProperty listener is not being called when deiconifying a maximized stage. Am I doing it wrong, or is this a bug in JavaFX? I'm using Java 1.8.0_65 and whatever verson of JFX comes with it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm also on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Things you forgot to mention can still be included by clicking the [edit] link below the tags...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in JavaFX that seems to come and go with different versions.
It is especially annoying as some components (such as WebView) refuse to repaint in this circumstance - presumably as it thinks the application is still minimised and therefore does not need to repaint itself.

From my own observations:

- jre1.8.0_73: Fixed
- jre1.8.0_111: Broken
- jre1.8.0_121: Broken
- jre1.8.0_131: Fixed
- jre1.8.0_152: Fixed

I am currently looking for a workaround with jre1.8.0_111 which is what we have to use (due to more serious bugs in 121 and 131).

Comment: My work-around is to record the maximized state in a boolean flag ('wasMaximized') and then call setMaximized(false) whenever iconifying the stage. Then the iconifiedProperty() callback calls setMaximized(true) if isIconified() is false and 'wasMaximized' is true. A silly hack, but it works.